# How do I properly install virtualenvwrapper on Mac?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I've gone through so many questions and Google Searches, and my command prompt still continues to say that no command "mkvirtualenv" is found.

I am trying to create a virtual environment to use Django on, but I can't with this problem in the way.

Comment: Did  you try this sudo pip install virtualenv or if you get an error sudo -H pip install virtualenv

Comment: try this Install pip 
 sudo easy_install pip

for installing Virtual Environment Wrapper

You should install virtual environment wrapper in your /usr/local/bin path.

cd /usr/local/bin
install your virtualenvwrapper with 

pip install virtualenvwrapper

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenvwrapper%5D+mkvirtualenv+not+found.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Homebrew, i've found [`pyenv-virtualenvwrapper`](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenvwrapper#installing-with-homebrew-for-os-x-users) to be lowest hassle.